# What's I(.) function means in default

Tags: functions, notation, tensors

I'm studying a paper called "aggregating Ordinal Labels from Crowds by Minimax Conditional Entropy"

There is a function I can't understand.

I emailed the author but he doesn't reply.

Does anyone knows what $I(xij = k)$ means ?

[image: section I don't understand]

Comment: By the way, there are no further explanations about the function in this paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).
$$\mathbb{I}(x_{ij}=k) = \begin{cases}1 & \text{if $x_{ij}=k$}\\0 & \text{if $x_{ij} \ne k$}\end{cases}$$

Comment: You saved my day, thank you.